# Responsive Issues - div class="row" and section title

Tags: css, responsive-design

Would greatly appreciate some help with my coding:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/1qvejx38/`
```

It seems like  does not work on my coding, which I noticed when examining the Chrome Developer. It does not detect the entire grid, which affects the third section when the browser is reduced to medium device width.

Also, the section titles do not align with the right border of the sections.

Could someone please give me some advice? I've been racking my brains out but I just cannot pinpoint where the fault lies.

By the way, this is an assignment for a course that I am taking at the moment. We are not allowed to use any CSS or JS frameworks.

Thanks very much!

Comment: include code in here not just linking to fiddle

Comment: Sorry, I am a new user so I am not yet familiar. Do I just copy and paste the codes here?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `width: 90%;` from `p`. Also add required `padding` for `p` and `h2`.

```css
/***** Basic Styles *****/

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 175%;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
color: #696969;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-size: 125%;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FF8C00;
width: 100px;
padding: 10px;
position: relative;
float: right;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

p {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
color: #4B0082;
   margin: 0 10px 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 65px;
}

section {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.box1a{
  border: 1px solid #696969;
  /** background-color: **/
}

.box1b{
  border: 1px solid #696969;
  /** background-color: **/
}

.box1c{
  border: 1px solid #696969;
  /** background-color: **/
}

.box2a{
  border: 1px solid #696969;
  /** background-color: **/
}

.box2b{
  border: 1px solid #696969;
  /** background-color: **/
}

.box2c{
  border: 1px solid #696969;
  /** background-color: **/
}

/*****Simple Responsive Framework*****/
.row {
  width: 100%;
}

/***** For Large Devices *****/
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-4 {
float: left;
width: 33.33%;
  }
}

/***** For Medium Devices *****/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-md-6 {
float: left;
width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
width: 100%;
  }
  .section3 {
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
}

/***** For Small Devices *****/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-sm-12 {
width: 100%;
  }
  .section3 {
margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<title>Assignment Solution for Module 2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<body>
<h1> Our Menu</h1>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
 <section class="section1">
  <h2 class="box1a">Chicken</h2>
  <p class="box2a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
 </section>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
 <section class="section2">
  <h2 class="box1b">Beef</h2>
  <p class="box2b">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
 </section>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
 <section class="section3">
  <h2 class="box1c">Seafood</h2>
  <p class="box2c">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
 </section>
<div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/1qvejx38/2/

Comment: Hi Felix, thank you so much! I think I understand where I have gone wrong. I will examine further. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly fine now. I have browsersynced to my phone and everything is great. I have added the colour scheme and it looks awesome now. Thank you again, Felix!